# How to show that reduced homology of a point $0$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to read about proof of theorem of singular homology of spheres here: [http://math.columbia.edu/~syu/s19-eat/s19-eat-notes-mar28.pdf](http://math.columbia.edu/%7Esyu/s19-eat/s19-eat-notes-mar28.pdf)

Before reading it I have to know many prerequisites on earlier pages.

[image]

> I am not sure how to deduce that : reduced homology of {p} is 0. Can you please let me know how to deduce it?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Indeed, what is $C_n(X)$ for a one-point space $X$? What are the boundary maps in the chain complex?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri It seems these details are not told in these notes for which I am studying. Please give some reference where I can study these 2 results?

Comment: Hatcher's book Algebraic Topology (http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) is freely downloadable. Chapter 2 is on homology, and it looks at a quick glance like the notes you are using are based on that.

Comment: By the way, the notes pretty explicitly are not using singular homology: they don't even define it. The notes are focused on $\Delta$-complexes and simplicial homology, and as they say, simplicial and singular homology agree on spaces for which they are both defined.

Answer (score 0):

A one-point space $X$ is a $\Delta$-complex with a single $0$-simplex and no simplices of higher dimensions. (In terms of the definition on p. 3 of the notes, the identity map $\Delta^0 \to X$ is the only $0$-simplex.) Therefore $C_0(X) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $C_n(X) = 0$ for all $n > 0$. To compute the reduced homology, we use the chain complex
$$
\dots \to C_2(X) \to C_1(X) \to C_0(X) \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0
$$
which is
$$
\dots \to 0 \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0.
$$
(In this setting, all of the chain groups are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, so $R=\mathbb{Z}$.) Your notes are sloppy and don't specify the map from $C_0(X)$ to $R$: in general it sends each $0$-simplex to $1 \in R$. In this case that means it is the identity map. Now you can compute the homology of the resulting chain complex: it is zero in every dimension.